# How can I get realtime network calls in BrowserStack app-automate?

Tags: browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

How can I get realtime network calls in BrowserStack **app-automate**?

There seem to be two options for me so far from what I have explored.

- Get network logs from BrowserStack.

  Issue: With this approach, I can get network calls only after the session completes. I can run checks only at the end of session, and not as the events occur.
- Use `mitmproxy`

  Issue: Wanted to avoid using an external dependency. With this I will also have to start a proxy server, which seems like an overkill for a feature BrowserStack should already have.

Could someone please share if they have better approaches to identifying network calls from BrowserStack test device?